# Can we say "torch relay" and "relay the torch"?

Tags: meaning

We saw

> this school is having torch relay

(maybe it's correct), but I don't know if *relay a torch* is right. Eg, *he is selected to relay the torch*. If not, how do we usually say it?

Comment: Longxianchen, you may want to check out [our sister site set up specifically for learners like you](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

The cliche I'm aware of is "...pass the torch"  which probably comes from the similar term in relay races, "pass the baton."  I would have written your first quote as "This school is having *a* torch relay..." . 
Now,  *passing* the torch means to hand it off to the next person. Prior to that, the owner is *carrying* the torch.

Comment: Well, no: *carrying the torch* has an entirely different connotation. Though I suppose if context made it amply clear that it's a literal usage, it could work.

Comment: @Marthaª I stand corrected-- thought the etymology was from Olympic torch-bearers.